# assets folder structure in cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to read the text file in cordova. For this I've created a **assets** folder (See the *cordova folder structure* image) and placed my text file in that but i'm getting the error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: json.txt`.

**Note:**
When i tried it in the Android native I'm able to read the file...

***Code***

```
String yourData = LoadData("json.txt");
```

---

```
public String LoadData(String inFile) {
    String tContents = "";

    try {
        InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open(inFile);

        int size = stream.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        stream.read(buffer);
        stream.close();
        tContents = new String(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("catch", e + "");
    }

    return tContents;

}
```

***Cordova folder structure***

[image]

Am i placing **assets** folder in the wrong position or am i doing any other mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual problem was, haven't mentioned assets folder in `plugin.xml`. After mentioning it everything working fine

**plugin.xml entry**

```
<source-file src="json.txt" target-dir="assets"/>
```

and use same method and structure which is in the question

Answer (score 1):

Well as i got to know Cordova access your file as a relative path. and it will assume you're using the www directory.

so if you want to access your file you can do like this below in Cordova plugin -

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///android_asset/www/json.txt", onResolveSuccess, onFail);
```

your file path will become something like this -

**`file:///android_asset/www/json.txt"`**

Comment: Hi Thunder, In this case also i'm getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:///assets/json.txt`

Comment: try to get the path of this file by right click on that file and copy path if option there

Comment: give me few mins i am creating myself and updating u

Comment: Okay Thunder :-)

Comment: cordova assumes all the paths as relative path , it will assume your path contains www directory , so in your case your path should become 

file:///android_asset/www/json.txt" , give a try to this

Comment: hope you got this , feel free to accept and upvote this

Comment: As you mentioned i've used `window.resolveLocalFileS.....` in js file and initiated the method as `Uri path = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/www/json.txt");
                    String newPath = path.toString();

                    String yourData = LoadData(newPath);` but i'm not getting the expected output. Can you plz check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163478/discussion-between-thunder-and-bahu).